# Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer? error

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to move on to the 'Detail' window when I touch the image of headerRight in the 'Main' window. But the "Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?" error keeps popping up.
I think

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DETAIL')}>
                    <View>
                      <Image source={search} style={{height: 30, width: 30,marginRight:20}}/>
                    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

this code is a problem, how should I fix it?

Also,

> Can't find variable: navigation

error appears when I erase the `const navigation = useNavigation();` code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Image,ScrollView,TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import MainScreen from './MainScreen';
import DetailScreen from './DetailScreen';
import { useNavigation, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
let search=require('./search.png')

function BackBtn() {
  return (
    <Image
      source={require('./leftarrow.png')}
      style={{marginLeft: 20, width: 15, height: 15}}
    />
  );
}



export default function App() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='MAIN'>
        <Stack.Screen name='MAIN' component={MainScreen}
          options={{
            title:'',
            
            headerLeft:()=>
              <View>
                <Text style={{fontSize:25,marginLeft:30,marginTop:-5}}>성북구</Text>
              </View>
            ,
            
            headerRight:()=>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DETAIL')}>
                <View>
                  <Image source={search} style={{height: 30, width: 30,marginRight:20}}/>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ,
        }}/>

        <Stack.Screen name="DETAIL" component={DetailScreen} 
          options={{
            title: '상세화면', 
            headerBackTitleVisible: false,
            headerBackImage: BackBtn,
            headerTitle:()=>(
            <View>
              <TextInput placeholder={'어떤 것을 찾고 계신가요?'} style={styles.input} autoFocus></TextInput>
            </View>
            )
        }}/>
        
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

);


}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input:{
    backgroundColor:'white',
    marginTop:0,
    marginLeft:0,
    width:300,
    fontSize:15,
    paddingVertical:10,
    paddingHorizontal:15
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<Stack.Navigator
screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({
              headerRight: ()=>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DETAIL')}>
                    <View>
                      <Image source={search} style={{height: 30, width: 30,marginRight:20}}/>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
            })}
>
########### your routes here !
</Stack.Navigator>
```

i use react navigation V6.0.10

let me know if you need more informations or explication !

Comment: The same error "Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?" appears even though I added the code.

Comment: I share with you the code of the app i work on now :) and it works good with me because i'm in the same situation.
i use reactnavigation V6.0.10
so in my screenoptions.
<Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerRight: () => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DETAIL')}>
                <View>
                  <Image source={search} style={{height: 30, width: 30,marginRight:20}}/>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>,
        })}
      >
i wish this will help you, let me know if you need more help !

Comment: i will modify my answer that you see it more clear !

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It works very well!! However, if you replace 'options' with 'screenoptions', an error pops up, so I just wrote 'options' and added 'navigation' and it works well. And I have to delete  'const navigation = useNavigation();' this code so that the error doesn't come up. Thank you so much!!!!!!!